# Help with proving the following points form a cyclic quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let ABC be a triangle and D, E and F be the points of tangency of its incircle with the sides BC, CA and AB respectively. Let P and Q be the intersectiom of DE and Df with the bisectors of the angles ACB and ABC respectively. Show that E, F, P and Q belong in the same circunference.

What I have tried so far is, I have shown that if X and Y are the intersection of the diagonal FP and EQ with the incircle , then if the triangle XYD is isoceles the proof follows.

To show this, I've tried to show that the angles ADX and BDY are equal.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't true in general.

Here is why. If points $E,F,P,Q$ were concyclic, the power ([see here](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/PPower.shtml)) of point $D$ with respect to this circle could be expressed in two equal ways :

$$DP.DE=DQ.DF\tag{1}$$

As triangles $CDE$ and $BDF$ are isosceles, (1) is equivalent to :

$$2DP^2=2DQ^2$$

itself equivalent to $DP=DQ$ which isn't true in general.

Take for example triangle $ABC$ right isosceles  triangle with right angle in $B$ (see figure) :

[image]

Fig. 1 : *In a visible way, $E,F,P,Q$ do not belong to a same circle (this can be established by computation).*

Comment: Some reaction to my text ?

Comment: Nice.......[+1]